# AngularJS ng-options custom attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ng-options

I currently have the following directive on my `select`.

`ng-options="option.value as option.title for option in exportTypes"`

$scope.exportTypes = an array of objects each with `title`, `value`, and `generatesFile` attributes. I'd like the `generatesFile` attribute to be added as a `data-generates-file` attribute on each `<option>` that is generated for this select.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: You could not use ng-options and create an option and use ng-repeat on that option then you can set attributes accordingly.

Comment: `ng-repeat` is slower and this has to be as performant as possible. [Look at the first answer for an explanation.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482817/what-are-the-differences-between-ng-repeat-and-ng-options-and-why-do-they-not-be).

Comment: Without creating the option elements yourself I don't believe you're going to be able to add custom attributes to them. Angular manages selects behind the scenes for you, allowing you to get back whole objects when options are selected rather than just the value of the `value` attribute, etc. I think your best bet is going to be `ng-repeat` on the options elements. Also, how is that less performant? It's performing similar iteration logic behind the scenes when you do ng-options anyway.

Comment: `ng-repeat` uses a new scope, whereas `ng-options` uses the current scope. I'm hoping I can use the former, but if not, I think I'll have to go with something like what you showed in your answer.

Comment: Gotcha. I still wonder if the creation of a new scope is really going to be an order of magnitude difference in performance, but I haven't done any benchmarking so I don't actually know.

Comment: It gets more significant as the list increases, and I need to make sure that this is fast even with a bunch of options being populated.

Comment: I'm not sure you're interpreting these benchmarks correctly, and if you have a enough items to cause a performance problem you would really just have a UI problem,  and you should probably use an autocomplete and not a dropdown.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @Dylan. I've been playing with [a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yxreWTQ8AZ24KeEiideb?p=preview) duplicating your scenario and even after adding thousands of items to the selects (in both setups) I can't tell a difference. Still figuring out how to get real benchmark numbers out of it, but as far as usability is concerned I see no difference. Each trip through the digest cycle seems to be about the same whether I'm using `ng-options` or `ng-repeat`.

Comment: The other, more performant option is to use the select as intended without attributes and just use the index to locate the 'generatesFile' in the object, on change.

Comment: @Dylan's suggestion is probably the best option. I've augmented my answer to show just how easy this is. You don't even need to use the index to reference the original object.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe someone will correct me but I'm pretty sure you won't get this kind of control out of `ng-options`. Angular manages the select behind the scenes for you when you use this, which is nice 90% of the time but can be limiting in situations like yours. I'm not sure what benchmarks you're looking at but I'd be willing to bet an `ng-repeat` on the option elements is comparable in performance to using `ng-options`.

I'd go with something like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedExportType">
    <option ng-repeat="exportType in exportTypes" data-generates-file="{{exportType.generatesFile}}" value="{{exportType.value}}">
        {{exportType.title}}
    </option>
</select>
```

---

### Edit:

Of course, this assumes you really do need that attribute on there. If all you need is access to that attribute on select then this is where `ng-options` shines. Simply remove the `option.value as` bit from your select and then you get the whole object back from your array when you make a selection.

http://plnkr.co/edit/6XPaficTbbzozSQqo6uE?p=preview

You can see in that demo that the selected item is the whole object, complete with `someAttr` property which was never used in the select at all. If you inspect the DOM you won't see it. Angular tracks all this behind the scenes.

Comment: I'll try out the edited suggestion, and I'll see if that works. It seems that it would just from looking at it now though.

Comment: Well considering that I included a working demo, I think it works ;)

Comment: Can't get rid of the blank first option even though I'm using `ng-init`. Thoughts? Otherwise this would be very awesome!

Comment: The blank option is probably stemming from an unassigned ng-model. If you set the ng-model to a default value in the controller the blank option will be replaced. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select

Answer (score 5):

Here is a directive which can be used to add custom attributes when using `ng-options` with `<select>`, so you can prevent using `ng-repeat`

```
.directive('optionsCustomAttr', function ($parse) {
        return {
            priority: 0,
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                scope.addCustomAttr = function (attr, element, data, fnDisableIfTrue) {
                    $("option", element).each(function (i, e) {
                        var locals = {};
                        locals[attr] = data[i];
                        $(e).attr(iAttrs.customAttrName ? iAttrs.customAttrName : 'custom-attr', fnDisableIfTrue(scope, locals));
                    });
                };
                var expElements = iAttrs['optionsCustomAttr'].match(/(.+)\s+for\s+(.+)\s+in\s+(.+)/);
                var attrToWatch = expElements[3];
                var fnDisableIfTrue = $parse(expElements[1]);
                scope.$watch(attrToWatch, function (newValue) {
                    if (newValue)
                        scope.addCustomAttr(expElements[2], iElement, newValue, fnDisableIfTrue);
                });
            }
        };
     })
```

And then in your select,

```
<select ng-model="selectedExportType" ng-options="option.value as option.title for option in exportTypes" 
                  options-custom-attr="option.generatesFile for option in exportTypes" 
                  custom-attr-name="data-generates-file">
</select>
```

Note:  This is a modified version of `optionsDisabled` directory mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202254/ng-options-with-disabled-rows)

Comment: You can replace the jquery based for each loop with native `angular.foreach`. Adding the 'title' property can also be done using `elem.attr`

Comment: I had to make two changes to make this work properly:

Using `data[i - 1]` caused it to leave the first option without the attribute and all the following options with the wrong value. `data[i]` worked for me.

Since the directive makes reference to `iAttrs.customAttrName`, I had to put `custom-attr-name` in the HTML instead of `custom-attr`

Comment: Taking into account @MichaelPlante's comment you didn't even test if the code you posted works...

Answer (score -1):

Or a simpler solution:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items" option-style="items"></select>
```

And the directive which inserts whatever you want in each option tag.

```
angular.directive('optionStyle', function ($compile, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 10000,
        link: function optionStylePostLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var allItems = scope[attrs.optionStyle];
            var options = elem.find("option");
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                angular.element(options[i]).css("color", allItems[i].yourWantedValue);
            }
        }
    };
});
```