# First option in the dropdown is not getting selected in an Angular app

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-model

I have following dropdown in the html template.

```
    <div class="row">
        <label class="text-label hint--top-right hint--large" data-hint="{{customer.config.METHOD.DESCRIPTION}}">Calculation Method</label>
        <div class="input-select">
            <select class="input-select__select" ng-model="customer.attributes.tradingParameters.method">
                <option ng-repeat="indicator in customer.config.METHOD.VALUE" ng-selected="customer.attributes.tradingParameters.method == customer.shortenIndicator(indicator)" ng-value="customer.shortenIndicator(indicator)">{{indicator}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm using ng-repeat to generate the dropdown from a CONSTANT config file. Below is the config file.

```
    vm.config = {
        'METHOD': {
            'VALUE': ['N - No', 'Y- Yes'],
            'Description': 'Some description while hovering over'
        }
    }
```

On valid response, I assign the response object with indicators to ***atrributes*** property in the controller. And then using the ng-model to select the appropriate value.
However the twist is, the server sends just a single letter indicator, while in the dropdown I MUST have indicator with some description like 'N - No'.

So I added a ng-selected expression which compares the indicator returned from server with shortened version. Shortned version is created by calling the ***shortenIndicator*** method in the controller which splices the indicator on the first occurrence of a space.

```
    vm.shortenIndicator = function(fullIndicatorValue){
        return fullIndicatorValue.slice(0, fullIndicatorValue.indexOf(' '));
    };
```

So this is kinda weird behavior where only the first option in the dropdown in not getting selected when its returned from the server. However if the server sends second or third  option its getting selected.

Comment: Have you tried using ng-options in place of ng-repeat? ng-options is usually best for a select drop down. This answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482817/what-are-the-differences-between-ng-repeat-and-ng-options-and-why-do-they-not-be

Comment: But can I have the same logic of ng-selected and ng-value? How do I add those attributes to options tag using ng-options?!