# Populating a Select Box with Nodejs Information

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I have a mongodb database that will house several department names. I want to http.get() the names from my nodejs server. From that get, I want to populate the names into a select box. The important part of this question isn't the node/mongo part, its the js/html part of, I have the response from the get, how do I put it into a select box? Here is my code:

The part of code:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8000/getData').then(function(response) {
    // code to place here       
});
```

And the html part:

```
 <select placeholder="Select a User">
    <option ng-model="selectUser"></option>
 </select>
```

Comment: can you post the JSON structure of your data?

Comment: You should explain what you tried to do and which is the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to put the data from the response object into a controller property like this:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8000/getData').then(function(response) {
    $scope.options = response.data;
});
```

And then you can use the ng-options directive from angular to populate the select box with values like this:

```
<select placeholder="Select a User" ng-model="selectUser" data-ng-options="option.Member for option in options">
 </select>
```

Comment: I believe this answer is the correct one. [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) is made for this very purpose. I think the syntax, while *almost* readable, is absolutely impossible to remember (`color.name group by color.shade disable when color.notAnOption for color in colors` uhhh... ). But I still believe using ng-repeat for selects is a mistake. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19558972/1497533.

Comment: This worked perfectly. It populates the data perfectly! My only issue now is that my data is undefined.... great. Perfect answer. Thank you a ton.

Comment: My réponse.data is actually a object like this [{_id: "57cec43a03b3ea1f11910042", dept_name: "test"}] How can I just get the dept_name out of there to put in the list?

Comment: `ng-options="option.dept_name for option in options"` assuming your object is $scope.options.

Comment: Wow perfect. Thank you ippi!!

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like:

```
$scope.values; //values from server
$http.get('http://localhost:8000/getData').then(function(response) {
console.log(response.data); //make sure that this is what you are looking for               
$scope.values = response.data;
            }); 
 <select  placeholder="Select a User" data-ng-options="option.name for option in values">
 </select>
```