# ng-repeat isn't showing json object items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I would like to know why my items aren't showing on the DOM. Although ng-repeat is making new table rows. When I console log books it shows up fine but not with `ng-repeat`. [Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfNav.png)

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-light table-hover">
<tbody  id="tableBookSearch">
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in books"><td>key : {{key}} value: {{value}}</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$.getJSON(googleAPI, function(response){
        $scope.books = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++){
          $scope.books.push(response.items[i]);
          console.log('pushed book : ' + i);
        }
        $scope.$apply();
        console.log('scope applied');
        console.log($scope.books);
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried doing this with a normal array and it also didn't show data. The reference isn't null either.

Comment: Please include the output of `console.log` as well.

Comment: If you `console.log()` your `response` what do you get back?

Comment: add your controller code.

Comment: Why you are using `push` here? you can do just `$scope.books= response.items;` without using  `for loop`

Comment: @RameshRajendran $scope.books = response.items; does work, however I was just using loops to ensure we were getting a correct return and binding correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-light table-hover">
<tbody  id="tableBookSearch">
<tr ng-repeat="(key, prop) in books">
  <td>   Key : {{key}}</td> 
   <td ng-repeat="value in books[key]>  value : {{value }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead using  ng-repeat go for ng-options in angular find @https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Why he need to use ng-option instead of ng-repeat?

Comment: ng-options is very convenient to use in angular. Check @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482817/what-are-the-differences-between-ng-repeat-and-ng-options-and-why-do-they-not-be

Comment: NgOption is only for select tag.  Please read this as well [What are the differences between ng-repeat and ng-options and why do they not behave the same way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482817/what-are-the-differences-between-ng-repeat-and-ng-options-and-why-do-they-not-be)

Comment: @RameshRajendran in performance aspect `ng-options` it's always best .

Comment: @supercool That's OK man.  whatever, this is not wanted for this question.

Comment: Ok will check let u know.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The environment I'm coding in is Angular2 and I thought it to be AngularJS. ng-repeat is a directive of AngularJS and to do something similar I would have to use *ngfor.