# ng-selected not updating the dropdown angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been working in AngularJS, when doing the below functionality, I still get an empty option as the first child of select element.

Here is my HTML Code Snippet

```
<select id="connectTV" aria-label="How many Dish TVs" ng-model="connectTVs.index" ng-change="onChangeMethod(connectTVs.index)" class="selector" aria-required="true">
           <option  ng-repeat="noOfTV in noOfTVs" ng-value="noOfTV.index" ng-selected="noOfTV.index == connectTVs.index">{{noOfTV.value}}</option>
</select>
```

JS Code

```
$scope.noOfTVs = [
                      {index: 0, value: 'How many Dish TVs?'},
                      {index: 1, value: 'Connect 1 Dish TV'},
                      {index: 2, value: 'Connect 2 Dish TVs'},
                      {index: 3, value: 'Connect 3 Dish TVs'},
                      {index: 4, value: 'Connect 4 Dish TVs'},
                      {index: 5, value: 'Connect 5 Dish TVs'},
                      {index: 6, value: 'Connect 6 Dish TVs'},
                      {index: 7, value: 'Connect 7 Dish TVs'},
                      {index: 8, value: 'Connect 8 Dish TVs'}
                      ];


$scope.onChangeMethod = function(connectTVsIndex) { 

    // Doing some actions
     $scope.connectTVs = $scope.noOfTVs[connectTVsIndex];
     $window.sessionStorage.setItem("noOfTVSelected", $scope.connectTVs.index);
}
```

Finally, here's the HTML which gets generated which has

```
<option value="? number:4 ?"></option>
```

[image]

Getting empty option as the first child of select element. Where I'm doing wrong? Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-options` for select rather than `ng-repeat`. The former has better [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482817/what-are-the-differences-between-ng-repeat-and-ng-options-and-why-do-they-not-be) for larger array sets and provides more flexibility.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.noOfTVs = [{
            index: 0,
            value: 'How many Dish TVs?'
        }, {
            index: 1,
            value: 'Connect 1 Dish TV'
        }, {
            index: 2,
            value: 'Connect 2 Dish TVs'
        }, {
            index: 3,
            value: 'Connect 3 Dish TVs'
        }, {
            index: 4,
            value: 'Connect 4 Dish TVs'
        }, {
            index: 5,
            value: 'Connect 5 Dish TVs'
        }, {
            index: 6,
            value: 'Connect 6 Dish TVs'
        }, {
            index: 7,
            value: 'Connect 7 Dish TVs'
        }, {
            index: 8,
            value: 'Connect 8 Dish TVs'
        }];
        $scope.connectTVs=$scope.noOfTVs[0];
        $scope.onChangeMethod = function() {
            // Doing some actions
            console.log($scope.connectTVs)
        }

    }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <select id="connectTV" aria-label="How many Dish TVs" ng-model="connectTVs" ng-change="onChangeMethod()" class="selector" aria-required="true" ng-options="noOfTV as noOfTV.value for noOfTV in noOfTVs">
</select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have make your answer in a plunker, but still I can see some errors when selecting the dropdown. https://plnkr.co/edit/14yiIyPKmWYzHbCxmzor?p=preview   .. change the dropdown values continuously from 5, 3, 8, default value, you will see the dropdown value doesn't change

Comment: @UI_Dev I have updated my code. The problem was in ng-change function, there was no need to reassign the ng-model value, the index was getting changed because of this. You can directly access the selected value inside the function call.

Comment: I see the issue again. Can you check the updated code once? Select 6 dropdown, then 1 and then go to how many tvs, still I cannot able to select the first dropdown

Answer (score 1):

It happens because your initial binded `ngModel` on your `select` is undefined.

`ng-model="connectTVs.index` $scope.connectTVs doesn't exist!

Fastest solution that fits with your issue would be to add:

```
$scope.connectTVs = {
    index: 0,
```

$scope.onChangeMethod = function(connectTVsIndex) {

```
// Doing some actions
 $scope.connectTVs = $scope.noOfTVs[connectTVsIndex];
 $window.sessionStorage.setItem("noOfTVSelected", $scope.connectTVs.index);
```

}
Finally, here's the HTML which gets generated which has

enter image description here

Getting empty option as the first child of select element. Where I'm doing wrong? Can someone help on this?

```
    value: 'How many Dish TVs?'
}
```

But I would add that adding an index property in this kind of object is useless given that you can access to it in your view with `$index`.

Working demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/mmD4mVUNxLr9sbojrCKc?p=preview