# Why on looping multiple arrays in AngularJS one of them looses its content?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have a table where I show the user permissions, permissions for the role and additional permissions  set to this user. When I select a role in the list I call the method renderPermissions, and, when I select an additional permission too. The additional permissions array looses content when I check to true some permission (in another array). Why? Cannot figure why.

I have tried testing in console what is the content of the three arrays all the time, and everything goes perfect, except when I loop the additionalPermissions array.

Permissions Table to show

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <label>Tabla de permisos seleccionados</label>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="permission in permissions track by $index">
            [[permission.name]]: 
            <i ng-if="!permission.selected" class="fa fa-ban text-danger"></i>
            <i ng-if="permission.selected" class="fa fa-check text-success"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Role select
    
        Rol del usuario

Additional permissions multiselect list

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label>Permisos adicionales</label><br/>
    <select name="role" class="form-control" id="permissionList" ng-change="changeList()" ng-model="additionalPermissions" multiple style="width: 100%;">
        <option ng-repeat="permission in permissions track by $index" value="[[permission.name]]" ng-disabled="permission.selected">[[permission.name]]</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

AngularJS Application

```
var app = angular.module('UsersApp', []);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
});

app.controller('UsersController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.permissions = [{"id":1,"name":"Visualizar desaf\u00edos","selected":false},{"id":2,"name":"Editar desaf\u00edos","selected":false},{"id":3,"name":"Crear desaf\u00edos","selected":false},{"id":4,"name":"Editar usuarios","selected":false},{"id":5,"name":"Eliminar usuarios","selected":false},{"id":6,"name":"Editar permisos","selected":false},{"id":7,"name":"Eliminar permisos","selected":false},{"id":8,"name":"Editar roles","selected":false},{"id":9,"name":"Eliminar roles","selected":false}];
    $scope.rolesPermissions = [{"name":"Super Admin","permissions":["Visualizar desaf\u00edos","Editar desaf\u00edos","Crear desaf\u00edos","Editar usuarios","Eliminar usuarios","Editar permisos","Eliminar permisos","Editar roles","Eliminar roles"]},{"name":"Admin","permissions":["Visualizar desaf\u00edos","Editar desaf\u00edos","Crear desaf\u00edos","Editar usuarios"]},{"name":"Editor","permissions":["Visualizar desaf\u00edos","Editar desaf\u00edos","Crear desaf\u00edos"]}];

    $scope.cleanSelectedPermissions = function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.permissions, function (permission) {
            permission.selected = false;
        });
    };

    $scope.renderPermissions = function () {
        console.log($scope.additionalPermissions);
        angular.forEach($scope.permissions, function (permission) {
            angular.forEach($scope.selectedRole.permissions, function(rolePermission) {
                if (rolePermission == permission.name) {
                    permission.selected = true;
                }
            });

            angular.forEach($scope.additionalPermissions, function (additionalPermission) {
                if (additionalPermission == permission.name) {
                    permission.selected = true;
                }
            });
        });
        console.log($scope.additionalPermissions);
    };

    $scope.changeList = function () {
        $scope.cleanSelectedPermissions();
        $scope.renderPermissions();
    };

    $scope.selectedRole = $scope.rolesPermissions[0];
    $scope.additionalPermissions = [];
    $scope.changeList();
});
```

As you see on render permissions first I loop the `$scope.permissions` and the with the rolePermission, if equal then mark the permission as selected. When I do exactly the same on `$scope.additionalPermissions` array it looses content and the permission didn't get marked as selected as I expected. Why is this happening?

**EDIT:** I managed to fix it, but I dont know why is this happening, could some AngularJS guru tell us why is this happening?

I changed the Additional permissions view code to this:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label>Permisos adicionales</label><br/>
    <select name="role" class="form-control" id="permissionList" ng-change="changeList()" ng-model="additionalPermissions"  ng-options="permission.name for permission in permissions" multiple style="width: 100%;"></select>
</div>
```

As you can see I deleted the options ngRepeat and added the ngOptions directive. Please, explain us why this works but options with ngRepeat doesn't works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: May be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19558972/9041122) could help you understand things better.

Comment: I think it solves my doubt. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. It could be solved addint ngOptions to the select instead the ngRepeat with the options tag.